# PowerShell timing loop doesn't complete, hangs at random spot

Tags: powershell

I've created a very simple function in a powershell module which should capture a keystroke if a key is pressed within a short time window.

```
function get-mycommand{
    $count=0
    $sleepTimer=2 #in milliseconds
    while ($count -le 100)
    {
        if($host.UI.RawUI.KeyAvailable) {
            $key = $host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey('NoEcho, IncludeKeyDown')
            return $key.character
        } else {
            $count++
            Write-Host $count
            Start-Sleep -m $sleepTimer
        }
    }
    return "fail"
}

function test-get-command{
    $myvalue = get-mycommand
    Write-Host  'return ' $myvalue
}
```

This works fine so long as I press a key quickly. If I don't press a key then it will count up to some random number, usually less than 20, and then stop updating. It won't do anything until I press a key and it never times out. When I do press a key, even after several minutes it will return with the character. I never see the 'fail' message at all.

Using a longer timer interval doesn't change anything.I've tried a sleeptimer of 2, 20 & 200. They all behave the same.

Comment: How are you launching this code?  This runs just as you would expect when run in the PowerShell.  I have confirmed that it does not function in the Microsoft Terminal app.  Are you trying it in the ISE or Terminal?

Comment: Sounds like the `if` branch is being chosen, try adding a `Write-Host "There's a key available"` statement on the next line after `if($host.UI...` to confirm

Comment: @FoxDeploy it works the same way in either case for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, **`$host.UI.RawUI.KeyAvailable` can have *false positives*** in *Windows PowerShell* as well as in *PowerShell (Core) up to at least v7.2.0-preview.9* (current as of this writing).

- *On Windows*, it seemingly thinks a key is available even when there isn't, so that `$key = $host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey('NoEcho, IncludeKeyDown')` is executed, which indefinitely waits for an *actual* keypress.

  - In a *regular console window* this seems to happen after a few iterations at the latest.
  - In *Windows Terminal*, it seems to happen consistently on the *first* iteration, so that your function produces no output at all.
- [GitHub issue #959](https://github.com/PowerShell/PSReadLine/issues/959) seems relevant, although it relates to the `PSReadLine` module.

  - While unloading the module (`Remove-Module PSReadLine`) - which you wouldn't want to do in a interactive session - does fix the problem in *regular console windows*, it doesn't help in *Windows Terminal*.

**Workaround**:

Replace `$host.UI.RawUI.KeyAvailable` with [`[Console]::KeyAvailable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Console.KeyAvailable)

Note that this limits use to *consoles* (terminals), but your original code wouldn't work in the obsolescent ISE anyway, because `$host.UI.RawUI.KeyAvailable` there seemingly *never* reports a pending keypress.

Comment: Thanks, @marcp - I've updated the answer to clarify. (I was hoping that it was implied that Windows PowerShell is affected too, due not excluding it, but I get that that wasn't obvious).